# Any tool for AWS console to see how all services are linked inside a account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any tool or some way in AWS console through which I can see how all the resources or services in one account are linked to each other? Eg. SQS is connected lambda and this lambda is connected Kinesis Firehose, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There are various third-party products that attempt to present visualizations of AWS resources, but they might not go down to the level of showing linkages.

[AWS Cloud Map: Easily create and maintain custom maps of your applications](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloud-map-easily-create-and-maintain-custom-maps-of-your-applications/) is a newly announced service that is specifically designed to track such linkages, but it seems to only work with certain services at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the AWS cloud map but I don't think even this shows the linkages(any at all) for the existing services. We can create new namespaces using it. But I don't see any option to see the map for the existing services which are not created using it.